# Class selector returns null when I test

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, insert, spiceworks

I have a snipper of set html.  The basic structure is

```
<div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="some_class another_class ticket_print_wrapper visible"></div>
</div>
```

So I am trying to insert another button via code.  To do this, I am using(crudely for now):

```
$(".ticket_print_wrapper").insertAfter("<p>Moo</p>");
```

There is a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zmxpt/

It doesn't seem to accept `".ticket_print_wrapper"` as an object. Could anyone break my sleepless agony on this one, please?

Comment: in your fiddle you have `ticket-print-wrapper` instead of `ticket_print_wrapper`.. is that a typo?

Comment: and also, I think you should read [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) documentation

Comment: Yep, right on both counts.  Ugh, don't code when sleepy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(".actions").append("<p>Moo</p>");` if you want to add another contenton the same level with two buttons.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmxpt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("<p>Moo</p>").insertAfter(".ticket-print-wrapper");
```

Syntax is newElement.insertAfter( target )
In your example, your target is ticket-print-wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

1 - you have a typo in your fiddle.

2 - [$(element1).insertAfter(element2), will insert element1 after element2. You are using it reverse.](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

http://jsfiddle.net/Zmxpt/1/

```
$("<p>Moo</p>").insertAfter(".ticket-print-wrapper");
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. `.ticket-print-wrapper` is not the same thing as `.ticket_print_wrapper`
2. You want to use `$().after()` instead of `$().insertAfter()`

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/Zmxpt/3/